# Performance Discrepancy between std::lower_bound and std::ranges::lower_bound

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Why does std::lower_bound outperform lower_bound on ranges in C++ benchmarks ?

My code is as follow :

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

std::set<int> my_set;

static void RangeLowerBound(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto i = 0; i <= 1'000'000; ++i) {
    my_set.insert(i);  
  }
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  auto search{900'000};
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto it = std::ranges::lower_bound(my_set, search);
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(it);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(RangeLowerBound);

static void StdLowerBound(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto i = 0; i <= 1'000'000; ++i) {
    my_set.insert(i);  
  }
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  auto search{900'000};
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), search);
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(it);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(StdLowerBound);

static void SetLowerBound(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto i = 0; i <= 1'000'000; ++i) {
    my_set.insert(i);  
  }
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  auto search{900'000};
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto it = my_set.lower_bound(search);
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(it);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(SetLowerBound);
```

https://quick-bench.com/q/iFTe4YdHpXq4f72itFZGU3AGW1w

in which case, std::ranges algo may outperform algos defined on data structures directly (e.g. std::set::lower_bound vs std::ranges::lower_bound)

Comment: The difference seem to appear only with -O3 optimization, For lower optimization levels the performance appear to be similar. This implies difference is in implementation rather than in algorithms

Comment: Why are you benchmarking the use of lower_bound with *`std::set`*? You should *never* call those functions on a `set`'s iterators. The general rule is that, if there's a container member function with the same name as an algorithm, use the member function.

Comment: @NicolBolas, it's just to see the difference (huge) between the different implementation

Comment: But it's a meaningless test. If you test it with a container that `lower_bound` *should* be used with, then you can draw useful conclusions. But testing the performance of two functions in circumstances that *should never occur* means nothing. You cannot draw any conclusions about either implementation.

Comment: The test is essentially between `std::ranges::lower_bound` and `std::lower_bound`. std::set::lower_bound is used as reference

Comment: Nobody in their right mind will use algorithm `lower_bound` on a `std::set`. Put the numbers in a `std::vector`, then the comparison becomes meaningful.